# Big-O running time of recursive function

Tags: recursion, big-o

What is the Big-O running time of the following pseudocode:

```
rec(int N) {
    if (N<0) return;
    for i=1:N {
        for j=1:N {
            print("waste time");
        }
        rec(N-1);
    } 
}
```

If my understanding is correct, the precise running time of this code would be

```
N^2 * 1 + (N-1)^2 * N + (N-2)^2 * N * (N-1) ... + N!
```

Or equivalently

```
(N-k)^2 * nPk from k=0 to k=N-1
```

Would the Big O runtime still be O(N!)? What if we nested the "waste time" loop even more? What if we replaced the "waste time" loop with something that takes 2^(N-k) time instead of (N-k)^2 time?

My guess is that the answer to all of these questions is still O(N!) because the last few terms of the series dominate. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: in all of the scenarios you described, it would still be `O(n!)` because that's what dominates the series - the factorial grows much quicker than the other factors, it quickly becomes the main bottleneck in the algorithm's running time.

Unless you replace the waste time loop with something worse than `O(n!)` (for example, something `O(n^n)`), it'll always be `O(n!)`.